# AWS::RDS::DBInstance is not being created from cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation

This is my cloudformation json code to create DBInstance. I have successfully created VPC and EC2 instances and added this code to create DBInstance. But I am having following error while updating my stack with new json file including this DBInstance code.

Unable to create the resource. Verify that you have permission to create service linked role. Otherwise wait and try again later (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 1b64b02f-255a-4f5d-b68a-b0bacf6f2dba)

```
"myDBInstance" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
  "Properties" : {
    "DBName" : { "Ref" : "DBName"},
    "AllocatedStorage" : "20",
    "DBInstanceClass" : { "Ref" : "DBInstanceClass"},
    "Engine" : "MySQL",
    "EngineVersion" : "5.7.17",
    "MasterUsername" : { "Ref" : "DBUser"},
    "MasterUserPassword" : { "Ref" : "DBPassword"},
    "DBParameterGroupName" : { "Ref" : "myRDSParameterGroup"}
  }
},
"myRDSParameterGroup" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup",
  "Properties" : {
    "Family" : "MySQL5.6",
    "Description" : "Cloudformation database parameter group",
    "Parameters" : {
      "autocommit" : "1",
      "general_log" : "1",
      "old_passwords" : "0"
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6zs5.png)

Comment: Am i using any features that is not accessible  from aws educate account. I am using aws educate account.

Comment: I am having a similar issue with a policy that allows rds:CreateDBInstance and works on one aws account. On another account with the same policy it requires that I add iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole to the policy or it will not create a rds instance. Has anyone seen something like this?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue earlier, actually, the response says itself whats the problem. 
 **"Unable to create the resource. Verify that you have permission to create service linked role. "**

Means the IAM user your using to create this resource doesn't have permission to create service linked role, So you need to add this permission to your IAM user policy as follows.

**Solution:**

```
{
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
   "Resource": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

AWS answers this specifically for RDS in their docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAM.ServiceLinkedRoles.html

```
{
    "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/rds.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForRDS",
    "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
            "iam:AWSServiceName":"rds.amazonaws.com"
        }
    }
}
```